# Как в List засунуть изображения из папки Resources?

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер!

```
List<Image> list = new List<Image>();
list.Add(изображения из папки Resources);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать?

Comment: А что у вас выставлено в качестве Build Action для этих картинок?

Comment: @VladD, стоит "нет".

Comment: То есть, в скомпилированном состоянии картинки не находятся _внутри_ exe-файла, а лежат рядом?

Comment: Ну, они лежат просто в папке Resources

Answer (score 3):

Просто создавайте объекты `Image` из файлов и кладите в `List`:

```
List<Image> list = new List<Image>();
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("путь к папке\Resources");
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg"))
{
    list.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
}
```

Если изображения небольшие и не предполагается возможность их изменения пользователем, например значки кнопок, то стоит подумать о том, чтобы включить их в качестве ресурсов в саму сборку. Подробнее про добавление ресурсов в сборку средствами VisualStudio в **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)**

Comment: Это сработает, если текущий каталог совпадает с каталогом программы. Но если программу запускают по полному пути...

Comment: @VladD само собой, но я надеюсь изменить что изменить путь на нужный, не является непосильной задачей

Comment: @VladD так лучше?

Comment: Да, так лучше, спасибо!

Comment: Изображения, я бы не сказал, что маленькие. И хотелось бы "прикрутить" к exe-файлу. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Максим это лучше отдельным вопросом оформить, а то каша получится.

Comment: @rdorn, почему? Вопрос же непосредственно связан с темой. Проблема ведь не решена.

Comment: @Максим по текущему вопросу, как он сформулирован, более чем. Упаковка ресурсов в сборку и доступ к ним - это отдельная история

Comment: @Максим добавил ссылку на документацию по добавлению ресурсов в сборку, там все просто в принципе.

Comment: @rdorn, мне нужно картинки с папки Resources привязать к exe-файлу. И чтобы кто бы не запустил эту программу, у него отображались картинки. А в твоем коде, нужно, как я понял, указать прямой путь до папки Resources.

Comment: @Максим а в каком месте по тексту вопроса я или кто либо другой кроме вас должен об этом догадаться? Прямой путь указывать не обязательно, можно указать относительный, и даже правильнее указывать относительный, абсолютные пути то еще зло. А про привязку ресурсов почитайте ссылку из ответа, если не получится, перенесу беседу в чат и продолжим

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36633/discussion-between--and-rdorn).